# HighCharts - how to show the lineborder in Area Charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with two series - area types,When series1 data is less than another series2 , then only the border line of the series1 must appear over the series2 data.
In high charts, do we have any attributes or method to show only the line border.

Comment: Please see the below link 

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-zindex/

Change the type to area to see the effect

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) arrange your series so that the one that will get hidden is on top

2) set your fillColor using rgba() values so that you can set the opacity lower, or set your fillOpacity lower, so that you can see both series no matter which one is on top.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.fillColor
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.fillOpacity